# Lost in Tensorflow github repository

Tags: github, repository, tensorflow

Is there a way to efficiently search for a specific function in a repository ?
For instance I was looking for the code for some of tensorflow.image functions but I am completely lost in the structure of their repository.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is sufficient for you and maybe there's a better method, but I find instead of using the plain function name, something like "def functionName(" gives much better search results (if your looking for the function definition).

Comment: If you are looking for functions in TensorFlow, clone and load it in PyCharm or other IDE. Then, it's very easy to find.

Comment: @nastchz yes of course you are right when you are searching a file however when you want a recursive search in all the subfolders of the repo (as you don't know which one is the right one) a simple ctrl+F doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Sung Kim I will try that at home however the company I work with is blocking git so... moreover using an IDE looks a bit too complicated for what I ask. Btw I still have not found the simple image folder or script where all the image relative functions are defined quite a waste of time.

Comment: @natschz I found it using the simple search bar from github it allows you to search every files in the repo apparently...

Comment: Oh didn't realize you where looking for the searchbar. But yea i think the postion of the searchbar suggests searching for a repository instead of searching the repository itself :P

Comment: Yeah that was stupid of me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `ipython`? Ipython will can locate the source of arbitrary functions. For that just install tensorflow and run:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
In [2]: ?tf.image
```

Output:

> Type:       module
>
> String Form:
>
> File:       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.py
>
> Docstring: ...

`tf.image` is therefore implemented in `tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.py`.

You can also use `?` for information about function such as `?tf.image.decode_jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

The correct path of all image functions in Tensorflow repo is tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops. Github is awesome as its search bar allows you to parse every file in the root folder.